# GoogleMaps Flutter Exceeded sample count in FrameTime Log

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

Hey when adding GoogleMaps to my project, it seems that anytime the map is dragged or the camera is moved there is a spam of logs for

```
I/Counters( 4961): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
```

This seems to be a common issue with GoogleMaps in flutter reported here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467381/i-counters-exceeded-sample-count-in-frametime-log) and [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83687)

P.S. Setting `myLocationEnabled: false`, will not solve the issue as this still occurs when manually moving the map

```
class MyMap extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMap({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: state.location ?? const LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 15.0,
      ),
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      myLocationEnabled: false,
      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
      scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
      rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know if there is an update on the best way to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

delete some layers from widget google maps flutter

```
  myLocationEnabled: false,
  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
  scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
  tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
  rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
```